# Am I assigning a value directly to a memory location with a pointer variable in C?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, variable-address

I've decided to complicate my life by learning C.  Currently I am trying to fully understand pointers.

So far this is what I understand:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    char var = 'A';
    // Iniialize a pointer variable to the ADDRESS of variable "var"
    char *ptr = &var;
    printf("%c", var);    // Output: 'A'

    // Change the VALUE at the memory location of variable "var"
    *ptr = 'B';
    printf("%c", var);    // Output: 'B'

    return (0);
}
```

But then I was looking into re-assigning a string to a variable, and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008756/11653053), where a pointer variable is assigned a value directly.

This is what I am trying to understand:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    // Declare a pointer variable
    char *ptr;

    // Assign a VALUE directly to a memory location???
    ptr = "String 1";
    printf("%s", ptr);    // Output: "String 1"

    return (0);
}
```

Also, if I assign a new string value to `ptr`, such as `ptr = "String 2";`, and also output the memory location after each assignment, I get a different memory location:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    // Declare a pointer variable
    char *ptr;

    // Assign a VALUE directly to a memory location???
    ptr = "String 1";
    printf("%s\n", ptr);    // Output: "String 1"
    printf("%p\n", ptr);    // Output: 0000000000404003 <- one memory location

    // Assign a new VALUE to the pointer variable
    ptr = "String 2";
    printf("%s\n", ptr);    // Output: "String 2"
    printf("%p", ptr);    // Output: 000000000040400F <- a new memory location

    return (0);
}
```

Am I really assigning a VALUE to the memory location the pointer variable is referencing?

Why does the memory location change when I assign a new value to the pointer variable?

Comment: `"String 1"` and `"String 2"` are constant strings necessarily at different memory locations. They aren't even the same string value. However, you indicate in the code comments that, `ptr = "String 2";  printf("%s\n", ptr); ` prints `String 1`. That's not making sense. Check that again and make sure.

Comment: When you assign to dereferenced pointer, i.e. `*ptr = ...`, you are changing *the value at the location* where the pointer is pointing to. When you assign to pointer, i.e., `ptr = ...`, you are changing *where* the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @lurker My mistake.  I wrote the wrong output.  I corrected it.

Comment: @howdoicode thanks, that makes sense. The rest of my comment explains the difference in pointer values.

Answer (score 2):

`pointer` hold reference to (address of) the object.

```
char *ptr = "string 1";
```

is the same as

```
char *ptr;
ptr = "string 1";
```

it assigns the pointer `ptr` with the address of the *string literal* `"string 1"`. String literals are null character terminated `const char` arrays.

When you :

```
ptr = "string 2";
```

you assign the pointer `ptr` with the address of another string literal. And as I wrote above is simply a `const char` array. Addresses of both string literals are different.

> ```
> ptr = "String 2";
> printf("%s\n", ptr);    // Output: "String 1"
> ```

It is not possible, and you post here different code than you run on your computer. It **will** print ***`String 2`*** for sure.

> ```
> // Assign a VALUE directly to a memory location???
> ptr = "String 1";
> ```

No, this assignment only assigns pointer `ptr` with the address of string literal which resides somewhere in memory. It does not allocate the space or copy this string anywhere.

The magic ***`*`***:

When you use the dereference operator `*` you access the object the pointer is referencing.

```
char str[] = "String 1";
char *ptr;

ptr = str;
*ptr = 'X';

printf("str = `%s` And its address is %p\n", str, (void *)str);
printf("ptr = `%s` it is holging %p address. Its address is %p\n", ptr, (void *)ptr, (void *)&ptr);
```

Output:

```
str = `Xtring 1` And its address is 0x7ffdc9047827
ptr = `Xtring 1` it is holging 0x7ffdc9047827 address. Its address is 0x7ffdc9047818
```

As you see it changes the first character of the `str` as pointer `ptr` holds the address of the first character of this array.

https://godbolt.org/z/x8PsW9vsP

Comment: For `ptr = "String 2";` is mistakenly wrote the wrong output.  I corrected it in my original post.

Comment: @howdoicode be more careful when you ask questions. Such mistakes waste time of many people

Comment: When you are assigning `ptr = str;`, what is happening here?  How come you don't use the `&` "address-of" operator, such as `ptr = &str;`?

Comment: @howdoicode https://stackoverflow.com/a/62210038/6110094

Answer (score 2):

To assign a value to an object using a pointer that points to the object you need to dereference the pointer as you are doing in the first your program.

```
*ptr = 'B';
```

As for this code snippet

```
char *ptr;

ptr = "String 1";
```

then there is declared a pointer that then is assigned with the address of the first character of the string literal `"String 1"`.

You can reassign the pointer like

```
ptr = "String 2";
```

but this reassigns the pointer itself not the object previously pointed to by the pointer. That is now the pointer points to the first character of the string literal `"String 2"`.

Pay attention to that you may not change the string literal using the pointer like for example

```
*ptr = 's';
```

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

But you can change a character array initialized by a string literal like

```
char s[] = "String 1";
char *ptr = s;
*ptr = 's';
```